# PHPUnit - suffix argument ignored in directory tag under testsuite

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I recently realized that I cannot run all my phpunit tests at once unless I use the "php artisan test", and I don't understand why. I would use the other option but I can't do coverage with that.

I assume it's somehow related to my configuration file being wrong because of a syntax change, or my directory being set wrong or something, because I can't find anything else.

The suite is found, but the suffix is not applied, whether I write it as ".php" or "Tests.php" or anything else. I know, because if I rename all my test files with Test at the end instead of Tests, then they suddently get recognized by phpunit. I also tried all numbers of directory options, like "./tests/Unit" and "./tests/Unit/*" but to no avail.

I would really appreciate some help if anyone has any idea what is happening, because it's driving me crazy. It took me a day to figure out I needed to rename my files just to make it work, and at this point I don't even want to do that unless I absolutely must, since there is this suffix feature.

I just want to understand why it does not work, and how to use it properly, in hopes of being able to learn how to use phpunit in the right way.

[image: Tests, configuration, and the tests being ignored on run]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. My tests work just fine if I use `<directory suffix=".php">./tests</directory>`. I don't use `php artisan test` because I'm on windows 
 7 and the colors just don't work. I use `./vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox` instead but I doubt that will change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked to fix the suffix. I tried reinstalling xdebug, php, and phpstorm. I ended up just renaming the files as I said. Only working solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential causes:

**1) Your `phpunit.xml` may not be configured properly.**

Try to change the "testsuite" and "coverage" section as shown below:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </include>
</coverage>
```

**2) Make sure all your tests methods use the `@test` annotation in the method’s DocBlock:**

```
/** @test */
public function your_test_method_name()
{
    ...
}
```

See: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html

> As an alternative to prefixing your test method names with test, you can use the @test annotation in a method’s DocBlock to mark it as a test method.

If you don't include the docblock, make sure your test method names start with "test":

```
public function test_method_name()
{
    ...
}
```

See: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

> The tests are public methods that are named test*.

Comment: Hi, well, all my tests begin with test, although the names are in camelCase. I previously tried adding the annotations to no result. I tried the example xml you provided, but it doesn't work. Even if I change the suffix to "Tests.php", which are the how my files end. I can run the tests individually in the class, or just a class, with PHPStorm. So they are seen as tests, and test classes. But phpunit ignores them when using the command line and testsuite. The suffix doesn't do anything and I don't get why...

Comment: @VladMB I've updated my answer. Please try the configuration I provided in your `phpunit.xml`. Since all your tests are in the "Unit" folder, your configuration should reflect this. By default, Laravel also provides a "Feature" folder. You can configure it as well just in case you need it later.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update, but I took that as an example. I had my file paths in order, but that is not the problem. Also, I'm the one who deleted the Feature folder before, since I didn't need it. As I said, the folders are detected, it's just the suffix that is not applied. If I make a test file that ends in Test.php, it works. To be honest I'll just do that as a workaround for now, but I feel like I have been robbed of a feature that should, and has previously worked. Probably reinstalling all my dev env will be the most sureway to get it to work. Thank you for the effort :)

Comment: @VladMB Thanks for the follow-up. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

> I know, because if I rename all my test files with Test at the end instead of Tests, then they suddenly get recognized by phpunit.

That sounds like the default configuration for phpunit and could be a sign that your configuration file you're trying to control the behaviour with is not *effective*. That is, however you run Phpunit, it is without the configuration file and the path only, e.g.:

```
/path/to/phpunit -- /path/to/test/directory
```

Phpunit then will work with the default configuration - but it must find it in the working directory. So either the configuration files have a name different to the names that phpunit uses for auto-detecting or they are not in the working directory, phpunit will start without loading a configuration file and just execute what it can find in the directory with the default suffix "Test.php".

(In Phpstorm the working directory can vary when invoking Phpunit, even between runs of the same action, but that just as a comment.)

What you can do in Phpstorm: Configure the Phpunit configuration file to load. A good way to do that is to specify a default Phpunit configuration file in *Settings* -> *PHP* -> *Test Frameworks* in the *Test Runner* Section for *Default configuration file*.

[image: Phpstorm Project Phpunit Default Configuration File]

Another thing is to specify the working directory explicitly in either the run action you already created which does not do what you want or by modifying the Phpunit run action template. Here a screenshot for the template:

[image: Working Directory in the Phpunit Run/Debug Configuration Templates (Phpstorm)]

A way to check the *effectiveness* is to make use of a bootstrap file in configuration and make it explode. Then you know whether or not something was effective.

Also PHpunit normally writes out the name of the configuration file if one is in use.

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to follow up, but I'm 100% certain that the proper configuration file is used, and effective. My test suites are listed, and I can generate coverage. The only thing that is ignored seems to be the suffix attribute on the directory tag. Honestly don't think I can debug what is at play for why that happens without pulling my hair out, as I've already invested a whole 2 days in investigating this consequence less issue. So I renamed them and called it a day, since everything else works. But thanks for the interest and effort, appreciate it :)

Comment: @VladMB: Yes, just configuration. Once set it actually works. Sometimes one can get lost in trouble-shooting. One way to do that is use non-standard configuration files in Phpunit. Or with the newer versions to re-init from scratch to get a different probe.  - And mind any extra configuration in the IDE if you're using it.